# Error on streaming video camera with libstreaming API with Android

Tags: android, video, streaming, rtsp, rtmp

I am tryng to use this API: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

I created the application on a rtmp server and set the rtsp on the exemple3.

The rtmp server receives the connection, but show a black screen.

In the LOGCAT, i see this error:

```
06-18 15:58:30.519: I/ACodec(25256): [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] Now Loaded
06-18 15:58:30.549: E/ACodec(25256): [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err -2147483648
06-18 15:58:30.559: I/ACodec(25256): setupVideoEncoder succeeded
06-18 15:58:30.559: I/ACodec(25256): [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] Now Loaded->Idle
06-18 15:58:30.569: I/ACodec(25256): [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] Now Idle->Executing
06-18 15:58:30.579: I/ACodec(25256): [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] Now Executing
```

**EDIT 1:**

Tested on a Galaxy S5 (Android 4.4.2)
Tested on a Moto X (Android 4.4.3)
Tested on a Tablet Foston 7" with android 4.0.1

Teste all with all resolutions provided by exemple3 and the same error

Comment: Please specify the device, system version, and camera params.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. If you will get any solution share it here.

Comment: you can try to use INDE Media Pack, it has a pretty set of samples and tutorials regarding streaming, for example how to stream from device to youtube through wowza: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-video-streaming-from-device-to-youtube

Comment: I tried that Marlon, but doesn't work...

Comment: I used the sample that comes in the package of Intel, and simply not enough to stream anything on my server. My server is OK and tested